# External usb storage hard drive unrecognized Anywhere - Tried the usual things

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have read the other relevant questions and searched the internet for hours.

My Maxtor one touch 4 external usb hard drive stopped being recognized. I have tried on different computers, operating systems, USBDeviceView, testdisk, device manager's disk management, It does not show up anywhere. It does though power up and make sounds as if it works, when you plug the power in or attach it to a usb port.

I am not very good with the hardware side of computers, though I think I read a comment somewhere saying someone used a usb to sata cable to attach it to another computer, could this help me at least retrieve the data on the drive? Someone said if the cables aren't correctly configured or attached it could burn the computer's motherboard etc??

I read on another question here with the same type of problem "I suspect the interface board on your external drive is bad, but the only sure way to test that is take the drive out of the enclosure and connect it to a known-good controller." I wonder if this could be relevant

I know now that Maxtor and Seagate branded hard drives are nightmares and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also assume that the interface board is damaged. Does the BIOS recognize the drive? If not then no software will be able to help you access it. If the interface board is indeed damaged then a USB2SATA adaptor will also not help. The only sure fire way would be to take the hard disk out of the external case and hook it up internally. Chances are you don't need any adaptors to do that. If the drive itself isn't damaged then you'll be able to access the data, keep the drive as an internal hard disk or place it into a new external case.

As for staying away from Seagate and Maxtor: Maxtor was bought by Seagate a long time ago and apart from Seagate there are only two other companies that manufacture hard drives these days: Western Digital and Hitachi. It's not like you have much of a choice. None is really better than the other.

Comment: I just checked the BIOS does not recognize the drive either no. I do not think it is physically damaged at all no. Thank you very much for the advice it helps a lot! I see, I have a mybook from WD which I have had no problems with so far, I am not sure on their reputation yet though.

Comment: Should I just google about how it hook it up internally or insert it into a new case as I have no idea to do this, I'm more experienced in software then hardware.

Comment: If the BIOS doesn't recognize the drive then the interface board is most likely busted. Also check for the most obvious like, is the USB cable placed firmly in the socket? May be there's a loose connection. Replace the cable if you have one handy to rule this out as a source of error. If all this doesn't help, then prepare yourself to open the drive or have someone do it for you if you have never handled hard disks before. There are also plenty of videos on Youtube showing you how to open specific external models which can save you quite some hassle. :)

Comment: Hooking up a hard disk internally is not rocket science, but if you have never done it before, then I'd suggest watching a vieo on how to do that. You'll get the point quickly.

Comment: Yes I have replaced both the usb cable and the power cable with new ones which are compatible and neither helped, but thanks. Thank you very much, I will research that and hopefully get somewhere! :D Ok.

Comment: Ah alright. Check out this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEDN_Cplf1k

Comment: I should mention that if your external drive uses the 2.5" or 1.8" form factor then you can only hook it up internally through an adaptor. Only 3.5" ones are directly compatible.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out looks like exactly what I need. Ok thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm sorry, the video that I recommended was absolutely useless. I didn't watch it before, but only googled it. Check out this one instead: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUO55J0haRI

The author explains it pretty nicely and gives you an idea of how to go about it. There's a second part where he shows how to hook up the HDD: http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_375147&feature=iv&src_vid=YUO55J0haRI&v=jPnDj6Px81c

Comment: Ok no problem thanks a lot for the links, I'll look at them both.

Answer (score 1):

take the drive out of the case and plug it direct into the motherboard. If it is not recognizable it is more likely dead(